# Pest on my chili plants

Tags: pest-control, pests, chili

I have a pest on my chili plants. It manifests as white powdery substance with black spots.

I am not sure What this is And How to treat It. I assumed It was a fungus, but now I also saw some small white worms or larvae. I sprayed with both white oil and fungus control on a two to three daily basis.

Maybe anyone can help identify and provide a good treatment?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you get a macro lens to have a close look? I'm wondering if you have a scale infestation, and that black stuff is poop.

Comment: I'll make some more pictures

Comment: I think the little green guys are the actual pests

Comment: Added more pics

Comment: Can you get a close up with better magnification ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And another bug to consider are lace wing bugs.  The control for this or scale or flea beetles or aphids is simply a NEEM drench.  Making a large container of NEEM solution, turning this plant upside down and gently swishing.  One treatment will not eradicate your problem.  Be sure to treat the top of your soil (do not soak just lightly spray).  It will take a bit of vigilance and be sure to check all of your other plants as they most likely will be hosting these insects as well in different degrees.

What kind of soil are you using?  Did you add anything such as bark or mulch from the out of doors?  Did you bring a new plant into your home a few months ago?  Get this plant dipped and look at your other plants.  If you have used garden soil get ready to transplant ALL of your house plants into new sterile bagged potting soil.  Plants indoors will not get these problems unless a new unknown plant is introduced to the family or someone has used garden soil or bark mulch from the garden.  Just takes ONE little dude that finds itself in a non competitive market to take over!  Send magnification of pictures for a bonafide ID.

Comment: These ones are outside actually and it's regular potting soil. Added dried natural fertiliser. Weird thing is my other plants don't suffer from it it seems, only my chilis

Comment: insects often are species specific.  For example, there are over 4000 types of aphids, and it seems I have more than one type in my garden!

Comment: I've been growing peppers in my little climate controlled grow house.  Same thing as chilis anyhoo.  They've been covered with lace wing and white fly...covered even though they've had regular dippings in NEEM.  The plants are healthy and dark green and glossy leaves and tons of chilis...Thai is my newest chili plant.  Doesn't seem to bother them at all...weird.  Yours look as if they don't get enough light which would make the leaves thinner, larger and more susceptible.  Glad you used potting soil.  All it takes is ONE egg, one insect that has no control predators...

Comment: Look at your other plants REALLY well with a 10X loupe.  I gotta feeling you might not only find lace wing, but white fly, aphids and spider mite.  The pothos you have can deal with insects because of its waxy thick leaves.  Dip your chili in Neem solution.  When you harvest chilis use a cup of hydrogen peroxide per gallon and dump your chilies into that solution to cleanse the neem off your crop.  I would consider a chili plant to be temporary and throw out the old plant to grow new chili plants.  Also, once every other month take all your house plants into the shower to be washed in cold H2O

Comment: And fertilizer is chemicals whether organic (or natural) or synthetic.  Not food and 'natural' means nothing in the label.  Make sure that the percentage of Nitrogen (nitrogen is nitrogen no matter its source) is LOWER than the P and K in your fertilizer formulation.  If you want fruit or chilis you have to keep that nitrogen below the percentages of phosphorus and potassium.  Also, too much nitrogen will cause even more thinning and enlargement of your leaves and will exacerbate any problems with insects.  Check out a REAL grow light.  I can't believe how my productive my chilis were 6" pots!